# mysql insert with a select

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing in PHP a mySQL query.  I would like to duplicate a row in a table in the database.  I would also like to insert a time stamp as to when that duplication happened with the NOW() function.

If I had a table named 'people' stuctured with the fields:

```
id, name, phone, dateCreated
```

and I wanted to duplicate this record I would do the following:

```
INSERT INTO people (id, name, phone, dateCreated)
SELECT id, name, phone, dateCreated 
FROM people 
WHERE id = '$id'
```

This will duplicate the record identified by the $id.  I would like to do this same concept but instead of copying the dateCreated, I would like the query to insert the current datetime via the NOW() function but I am not sure how to structure this type of query.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO people (id, name, phone)
SELECT id, name, phone
FROM people
WHERE id = '$id'
(dateCreated) value (NOW())
```

How would I structure the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO people (id, name, phone, dateCreated)
SELECT id, name, phone, NOW()
FROM people 
WHERE id = '$id'
```